# A generalization of a theorem of Grothendieck

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, banach-spaces

In this question the norm of $L^{P}[0,1]$ is denoted by $\parallel    .  \parallel _{p}$.

Let $p$ and $q$ be two arbitrary real numbers with $2<p<q$.

> Assume that $S$ is  a subvector space of  $L^{q}[0, 1]$ such that the identity operator $\text{Id.}: (S, \parallel  . \parallel _{p}) \to (S, \parallel . \parallel _{q})$ is a bounded operator.  Does this implies that $S$ is  a finite dimensional space?

If I am note mistaken, this is proved for $p=2, q=\infty$, by Grothendieck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.  The condition implies that the subspace is isomorphic to a Hilbert space.  In fact, Kadec and Pelczynski proved that   a subspace of $L_p$, $2<p<\infty$, is closed in $L_r$ for some $r<p$ if and only if the subspace is isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Kadec, M. I.; Pełczyński, A. Bases, lacunary sequences and complemented subspaces in the spaces Lp. Studia Math. 21 1961/1962 161–176.

Or look at the book by Albiac and Kalton.

Comment: Prof. Johnson, Thank  you very much for your answer. So we need to know that for every $p>2$, $L_{p}$ contains  an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, isometricaly. is it obvious?(I apologize if this question is elementary)

Comment: @AliTaghavi: What you need to know is that $L_p$ contains an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, *isomorphically*.  It is not obvious, but it is true and classical.  The usual proof is that Khintchine's inequality shows that the span of the Rademacher functions is such a space.

Comment: Or, if you want an isometric infinite dimensional Hilbert space in $L_p$, consider the closed span of an independent sequence of $N(0,1)$ random variables.

Comment: Yes, of course, silly of me to forget that.  I guess I got too hung up on the fact that an isometric embedding wasn't strictly needed here.  Incidentally, it's worth noting that even though an isometric embedding isn't necessary, it's better than the isomorphic embedding I suggested, for which the norm of the embedding blows up when $p \to \infty$.